# Google Sheets Filters

Tags: regex, filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Unsure if anyone can help me with this question, but hours of google searching has not helped find an answer...

I'm creating a spreadsheet with a list of items. These items each have an associated percentage with them. While I know I can break up the item name and percentage into 2 different columns, I am wondering if there is another way to solve this problem.

Here is an example of what the column might look like: http://prntscr.com/nwzutl

My Goal is to create a filter on the column, currently, it looks like this: http://prntscr.com/nwzv7z

Ideally, I would like to somehow exclude the percentages So all values in the column can be filtered on a "Text contains" basis of (for this example) "Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3". Ultimately something like this: http://prntscr.com/nwzyfi

Sadly I cannot seem to figure out if this is even possible to do and/or how to do it.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but if you are going to use filter by condition (as opposed to value), you could use a custom condition and in the place where you would normally refer to the cell, could you not refer to something like (maybe with a range where I have the cell) =left(A6, search(" (",A6)-1). Perhaps slapping on an iferror in case of unanticipated format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this only with helper column and filter by that:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\((.*)\)", "")))
```

[image: 0]